# Parse items in a html file in python (akin to what the JSON module does)

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to break down a web page which is made in HTML; in something like a dictionary of dictionaries; similar to what you get when you use a JSON file and load it in Python with the JSON module.

I am aware that I can parse the HTML myself, but it is quite a large task, especially for pages that hold a lot of tags and entries. In particular would like to get only specific data from the HTML page; so I was hoping that there is a python library that is able to do the same that the JSON module does.

Comment: [Beautiful Soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks!!